# How to change SOAPException ResponseCode

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, exception, soapexception

I am using `SoapException` to handle invalid inputs and all other kind of exception handling in my web service. It's working fine and I am able to format and return proper information to client. I am following a method similar to the one explained here 
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/throwing-better-soap-exceptions.html

Now I want to change the response code it returns when a `SoapException` happens (*ResponseCode: 500 Internal Server Error*).

Following is the default response code am getting in addition to my own custom `XML` data when a `SoapException` occurs. I want to change the `ResponseCode` to 200.. Is it possible and how?

```
ResponseCode: 500 (Internal Server Error)  
Connection:Close  
Content-Length:494  
Cache-Control:private  
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8  
Date:Tue, 25 Jan 2011 06:59:30 GMT  
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/8.0.0.0  
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
```

Comment: found the answer  ((System.Web.HttpContext)(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.HostContext)).Response.StatusCode = 200;

Comment: @Ariz: if that's the solution you chose, then you chose to violate the SOAP standard. The code has to be 500.

Comment: Since some browsers do not forward exception content to flash which is consuming the webmethod, I also want to change the statusCode to 200. However, the solution does not work for me. `((System.Web.HttpContext)(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.CallContext.HostCont‌​ext)).Response.StatusCode = 200; throw new SoapException();` still returns response code 500

Answer (score 2):

In support of John Sauders' word of warning above, according to WS-I Basic profile:

"R1126 An INSTANCE MUST use a "500 Internal Server Error" HTTP status code if the response message is a SOAP Fault."

http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.0-2004-04-16.html#refinement16488480